# Fire Absolute "Real" Click without Element using javascript or AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, mouse

is there any possible way to click on page , without any DOM relation , wherever the cursor position is , Fire mouse click ?

using javascript or AS3

thanks

Comment: The mouse is handle by the operating system, javascript and flash can't access to OS Mouse and trigger mouse event directly.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Aaron Something , not able to be done : D

Comment: Ha, okay. Well there might be a "near" solution depending on what you're trying to do, which is why I asked.

Comment: @Aaron , Well , it is about an iframe ... , Cross-Domain ,

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Mouse events are sandboxed to the current page in both AS3 and JS.

Comment: yeah , btw , just figured , it out